# Multiplas querys usando como elemento de busca o resultado da query anterior no mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Eu tenho uma api em NodeJS e estou usando o MongoDB com as seguintes collections:

- Notifications:

```
{
 _id: '0001',
 userId:'1',
 userNotifications: [
   {
      type: 'comment',
      userActionId: '2',
      target: 'id da imagem',
      viewed: false,
    },
    {
      type: 'like',
      userActionId: '3',
      target: 'id da imagem',
      viewed: false,
    },
]},

{
 _id: '0002',
 userId:'2',
 userNotifications: [
   {
      type: 'like',
      userActionId: '1',
      target: 'id da imagem',
      viewed: false,
    },
    {
      type: 'like',
      userActionId: '3',
      target: 'id da imagem',
      viewed: false,
    },
]}
```

e a collection users

```
{
 _id:'1',
 username: 'user1',
 email: 'useremail@email.com',
 avatar: 'avatar-url'
},
{
 _id:'2',
 username: 'user2',
 email: 'useremail@email.com',
 avatar: 'avatar-url'
},
{
 _id:'3',
 username: 'user3',
 email: 'useremail@email.com',
 avatar: 'avatar-url'
},
```

O uso vai ser o seguinte: O usuário vai solicitar todas as notificações, então preciso que a query pegue na collection `notifications` o documento referente à este usuário pelo atributo `userId`.

Com os dados desse documento, preciso pegar os dados de cada usuário que estão no array `userNotifications`.

A ideia é ter um resultado assim:

```
{
 _id: '0001',
 userId: '1',
 userNotifications: [
   {
      type: 'comment',
      userActionId: '2',
      target: 'id da imagem',
      viewed: false,
      userInformation:{
        username: 'user2',
        email: 'useremail@email.com',
        avatar: 'avatar-url'
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'like',
      userActionId: '3',
      target: 'id da imagem',
      viewed: false,
      userInformation:{
        username: 'user3',
        email: 'useremail@email.com',
        avatar: 'avatar-url'
      }
    }
 ]
```

Qual a melhor maneira de se fazer isso? Tentei usar `aggregation`, mas não consegui nem pegar só o documento referente ao usuário da collection  `notifications`

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, gostaria de obter todas as notificações de um usuário através do **ID**.

Se for isso não precisa usar o **aggegation**, basta fazer o seguinte:

```
const { _id } = req.user
const getNotificationByUserId = await collection.find({ userId: _id })
```

Vou assumir que está trabalhando com **Express js** e **Passport.js** poderá encontrar em **req.user**

Se não estiver usando **Passport.js**

```
const { _id } = req.session.user
const getNotificationByUserId = await collection.find({ userId: _id })
```

Precisa antes obter o **ID** do usuário para depois trazer as notificações do mesmo `getNotificationByUserId = await collection.find({ userId: '0001' })`
Para mais informações sobre com obter as informações do usuário através da url acesse o link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54854911/how-to-show-logged-in-user-info-in-all-routes-nodejs